# GWT SSLContext.setDefault(SSLContext) Jetty exception

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, ssl, embedded-jetty

I am trying to execute the following code in GWT Jetty development mode

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

but I am getting this exception

`SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.net.ssl.SSLPermission setDefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:301)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.setDefault(SSLContext.java:91)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems self-explanatory: this is not allowed on AppEngine (see `com.google.appengine.tools` in the stacktrace).

If you don't intend to use AppEngine, disable it (in Eclipse, uncheck the box in the project preferences) and revert to the *standard* DevMode.

Comment: I have to develop the whole project with appengine so I cannot disable it.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't use `SSLContext.setDefault()`